# Issues Structuring Private Permissions For Cloud Applications

Tags: wolfram-cloud

I want to deploy an application to the Wolfram Programming Cloud set up with private permissions. I have been testing this functionality and getting behaviors I can't explain or overcome.

The model syntax I'm using is from the help "Wolfram Language How To" -- "How to Set Cloud Object Permissions" -

```
CloudDeploy[APIFunction[{"x" -> "Integer"}, #x^#x &], Permissions -> 
  {{"user@email.com"} -> "Execute"}]
```

For my testing purposes, I have simplified the example while maintaining the same syntax --

```
CloudDeploy["Hello", Permissions -> {{“gmailuser@gmail.com"} -> "Execute"}]
```

For this purpose, I set up a free Cloud account using gmailuser@gmail.com for that purpose. (NB: I am not showing the actual email. "gmailuser@gmail.com" is a dummy for the purposes of this post.

I'm running this in a notebook using Mathematica 10.0.2.0 on Yosemite. I am logged into my Cloud account using my primary Wolfram user ID.

In testing this functionality I always begin by quitting the kernel. The first time I run the Deploy function I get this error --

```
StringJoin::string: String expected at position 2 in user-<>None. >>
```

and I also get a CloudObject[URL] as output.

Interestingly, if I quit the kernel and run

```
CloudDeploy[APIFunction[{"x" -> "Integer"}, #x^#x &], Permissions -> 
  {{"user@email.com"} -> "Execute"}]
```

in the "How To" notebook I get the same "StringJoin" error along with a URL.

The second time the Deploy function runs, there is no "StringJoin" error.

With regard to the URLs that are returned:

I paste them into a "new Private Window". As expected, a sign in box is returned requesting Wolfram ID and Password.

However, after entering The Wolfram ID and password (I am using as ID the email above -- "gmailuser@gmail.com").

The following message is always returned: “Something Went Wrong” “Oops. An error occurred. Please try again.” "If you continue to experience problems, please contact us."

I know the password is correct because if I enter the incorrect password, I am told that the account is not recognized.

This is a threshold issue I would like to get past before investing a lot of development time.

I would appreciate any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 3):

- See Wolfram How to [Set Cloud Object Permissions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/SetCloudObjectPermissions.html)
- By default CloudDeploy generates a CloudObject with permissions:
  "Owner" -> {"Read", "Write", "Execute"}.
  So you can leave out this option until you want others to visit your web application.
- To see the permissions of a CloudObject execute:
  Options[CloudObject[...]]. Here you must paste in the whole CloudObject with its live link. Mouse over it to be sure that it's the real active thing.
- View or execute the API in your web browser. You shouldn't have to do any cutting or pasting, much less open a "new Private Window," whatever that is. Just click the CloudObject link!
- Add an identifying string such as "MyFirstWolframCloudTest" as a second CloudDeploy argument. This will save you from cluttering your cloud directory space with a lot of unidentifiable objects.